# Maximal number of zeroes of analytic function on each fiber is finite

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

Let $f(z,w)$ be a holomorphic function on the polydisc $D\times D\subset \mathbb{C}^2$. Suppose that the zeroes of $f$ do not accumulate on $D\times\partial D$. Is it true that
$$ \text{max}_{z\in D}\# \{w\in D\mid f(z,w)=0\}<\infty $$

By the identity principle, the quantity $ \#\{w\in D\mid f(z,w)=0\}$ is finite for every $z\in D$. Moreover, by Rouché's theorem it is locally constant in $z$. However, because $D$ is not compact, I do not see how to conclude.

Comment: Do you mean $\#\{w \in D \mid f(z,w) = 0\}$?

Comment: Yes thank you. I fixed this now.

Comment: A function that is locally constant is constant on compact connected sets, e.g. closed disks.  A function that is constant on the closed disk of radius $r$ centred at $0$ for all $r < 1$ is constant on $D$.

Comment: My discs are meant to be open. But what you said is true without the compactness assumption right? I forgot this basic fact…

Comment: $D$ is an open disk, but it is the union of an increasing sequence of closed disks.  A function that is constant on each of the closed disks is constant on the open disk.

Comment: I see your point and I appreciate your responses. Just to make sure, though, do you agree that a locally constant function on any topological space is constant on each connected component? I don't see see how $D$ having a compact exhaustion is relevant.

Comment: Hmm, yes: if $f$ is locally constant and $c$ is any value of $f$, the inverse images of $c$ and its complement are disjoint open sets whose union is the whole space.  So if the space is connected, the function must be constant.